# C++ static members in static functions and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

How to create a static function whose variables need not to be created within it (for computational issues), taking into account that this function can be called by different threads?
Example:

```
class calcul {
    static double **v1, **v2, ...,**vn;

public:
    calcul();
    ~calcul();

    static void matrix();
};
```

such that `matrix()` uses `v1`, ..., `vn`.

The question is: when having multiple call for `calcul::matrix()` from different threads, would this create conflicts i.e. v1 related to thread A can be modified by thread B?

My objective of using 'static' is ergonomic in the sense that I would not each time need creating a corresponding object. In fact Class 'clacul' would be part of a library that needs to be used for real-time applications. That means that calcul() could be called each milliseconds for instance.

Comment: Why cant' v1, v2...be local variables in matrix? Whey do they need to be static?

Comment: For computation time issue. Imagine that v1.. vn are big size arrays for instance

Comment: I cannot really combine the first sentence with the last in any way that would result in a clear question. Perhaps try to re-phrase it, as-is I have no idea what you are talking about. Static variable initialization? Parallelism and thread safety? Both, neither, something else entirely?

Comment: In fact I have two questions, but I will try to rephrase my question

Comment: I've come across with the same question for the same reason. Answer is, to use std::vector or std::valarray that uses heap memory and forget about static, assuming heap is usually large enough, as oppose to stack, which is the primary reason you want it be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to create static variables is to declare them as you have, and then define them;

```
double calcul::v1, calcul::v2;   // same for other variables
```

This type of definition of the static variables has to occur in exactly ONE translation unit (aka source file which becomes an object) within your project.

If you wish to call your `calcul::matrix()` from multiple threads, then each of those threads will need to synchronise access to the static variables (for example, using a mutex).    Otherwise you get problems such as race conditions, operations being preempted when partly completed, etc.   That can mean variables getting unexpected values.

Comment: Should I understand that static members are not advisable for multi threading?

Comment: In broad terms, statics are not advisable with multithreading unless access to them is synchronised.   Same with any variable shared between threads, static or not, if there are concurrent readers and writers.    Statics introduce plenty of other concerns too, which is why they are generally discouraged - although they have their place.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the values non-`static` since they are only used locally in the function:

```
void matrix() {
    double v1, ..., vn;
    // ..
}
```

Or you could introduce some kind of synchronization primitive into matrix to prevent multiple threads from simultaneously accessing it:

```
class calcul {
    std::mutex mtx;
    static double v1, ..., vn;
};

void matrix() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    // ...
};
```

Lastly if your compiler supports it, you could make the variables `static thread_local`:

```
class calcul {
    static thread_local double v1, ..., vn;
};
```

Which does, from [basic.stc.thread]:

> 1 All variables declared with the `thread_local` keyword have *thread storage duration*. The storage for these
>   entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created. There is a distinct object or
>   reference per thread, and use of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.
>
> 2 A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before its first odr-use (3.2) and, if constructed,
>   shall be destroyed on thread exit.

Comment: But the problem consists in the fact that if v1, ... vn are big size-arrays, then you will have computational-time issue; that is, the manner you propose is not efficient in terms of processing time.

Comment: @polar I proposed three things. There is no "the manner" I proposed.

Comment: Thanks Barry, but I see that stuff are getting complicated. My objective of using  static is for ergonomic reasons, i.e. using matrix() without creating an object. I see that it is not so simple to achieve this...

Comment: @polar Wrong use of ergonomic aside, if you have multithreaded code you need to that avoid data races where different threads are reading/writing the same variables. You can do that by either having the threads just use entirely different variables (my 1st, 3rd proposal) or by carefully controlling access so that only one thread has it (my 2nd). "Stuff are getting complicated"? Not really.

Comment: @polar I think you have learned something about C++ that is not correct, and as nobody seems to find out what it is, could you edit your question and give [an mvce example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates why you think adding the keyword `static` somewhere makes your code "ergonomic" and "efficient in terms of processing time"? But when it comes to threading, letting multiple methods work with a single static data is like letting multiple people write on the same notebook at the same time. You want to rip of a sheet for each person, and then join all the pages afterwards.

Comment: Thanks taoufik. What do you mean by mvce example please?

Comment: @taoufik Good analogy with the notebook.

Comment: @polar click on the link [an mvce example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the blue. It explains it all.

Comment: @taoufik, Just have updated my question. I will try to add  an example.

Comment: @polar your question is still not explaining much. As SO is not a chat platform, I suggest you read the help on how to ask a good question first. May be the best thing to is to write a fully working programme and post it, with your question asking "how to make this ergonomic/realtime/runs in milliseconds/computational issues" (with a bit more explanation that just those words). One single question per posting.

Comment: Your question is full of incorrect assumptions...  threading != realtime; local variables != slow; passing a large structure by reference to a function != slow; passing data by reference or heap data != 'need creating a corresponding object'

Comment: @taoufik "Your question is full of incorrect assumptions". Can you please be more specific and indicate where exactly are these errors?

Comment: To have a code running in real-time (some time at the frequency of 10 ms), you are brought to make multi-threading. As for local veriables, declaring them inside the function (calcul in this case) make the code slower. This is a fact. Especially if you need to declare large size arrays (let say an array of 1200x600, like an image frame). I have not mentioned passing variables through reference. Finally, why do I need to create an object to call calcul(). Imagine you have dozens or hunders functions like calcul(). Do I need to declare all there objects (going back and forth from .h to .cpp)

Answer (score 0):

The static variables are from your class calcul namespace, and are allocated only once on memory, thus being the same for every object or thread you have.

Whenever you are trying to access the same variables (same memory address) from different threads, you need to work with Mutex or Semaphores, in order to perform transactions/operations safely.

Example:

```
#include <mutex>

class calcul{
    std::mutex mtx;
    ....
}

void matrix()
{
   //lock the resources below to the current thread only
   mtx.lock();

   //do stuff with the variables (common resource)

   mtx.unlock(); //when the current thread is finished, unlock the resource.
}
```